# using updateOne inside a map, setting the filter to the unique id , $set is to the document and upsert is true. Even then new document is created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[image]

here is my code in the controller from where i am getting the records from my google calendar API and then passing that data to this function and the code inside the function which inserts the document (records) looks like this as below:

```
Holiday.bulkWrite(
    holidays.map((holiday) => ({
        updateOne: {
            filter: { holidayId: holiday.id },
            update: { $set: holiday },
            upsert: true,
        },
    }))
)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am facing an issue where the document should be upserted but instead creating new even when the filter matches

Comment: if it's creating a new document then by definition the filter is not matching,  it's probably a value or type mismatch. make sure `holiday.id` is actually the value you are expected. the most common issue i see is that it's string instead of ObjectId when it comes to these types of "problems"

Comment: its not obejctId its string for both and still creating issues.

Comment: recheck the question i edited and inserted the image as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly the issue is because it is not Mongo related but code related, from what it seems you are just using the wrong field for the filter.

`holiday.id` is null, and we can see that the "inserted" documents do not have such field. You are basically executing the following update:

```
db.collection.update({
  holidayId: null
},
{
  "$set": {
    holidayId: "123"
    ... other fields
  }
},
{
  "upsert": true
})
```

I believe this simple fix would solve your issue, change `.id` To `.holidayId`:

```
Holiday.bulkWrite(
    holidays.map((holiday) => ({
        updateOne: {
            filter: { holidayId: holiday.holidayId },
            update: { $set: holiday },
            upsert: true,
        },
    }))
)
```

Comment: thank you so much, for replying to a silly mistake. this was actually the solution...many thanks